# Mocking the openDialog box that opens the dialog to select file name from drive

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am unit Testing the dialog boxes.

Here is code:

```
string fileName = this.uiService.OpenDialog(
    strExtensions, 
    this.resourceManager.GetResourceString(
                   StudioResourceManagerName.StudioResourceManager, "IDC_Open"),
    strInitialLocation);
```

I am using `moq` for mocking and I am able to successfully mock this but my next statement after this is calling a method that takes the filename entered in this Dialog box as argument. So how do I mock this dialog box in Unit Test cases so as to get the `filename` inside the called method? I mean how to pass `filename` inside the Unit Test case so that it will get inserted to the next method call?

Comment: I'm disappointing to find out this is not about making fun of (i.e. mocking) openDialog boxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you aren't too picky about what parameters are passed to the `OpenDialog` method , you can setup the mock service method like so:

```
mockUIService
   .Setup(_ => _.OpenDialog(It.IsAny<String>(), 
                            It.IsAny<String>(), 
                            It.IsAny<String>())
   .Returns("SomeFakeFileName.ext");
```

It will return the hardcoded filename `"SomeFakeFileName.ext"` to your SUT.

Similarly, if your service also offers a stateful "last FileName" property:

```
mockUIService
   .SetupGet(_ => _.FileName) 
   .Returns("SomeFakeFileName.ext");
```

Comment: thanks StuartLC , can u suggest some good book or online links from where one Read about Advanced Mocking and Unit Testing Techniques for View models or dialog boxes. I am sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this thing.